# Create dynamic Input Gridiew columns runtime using jquery asp.net web form

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have requirment by boss to create a page where user can create dynamic column in gridiew asp.net page at run time ..for data entry purpose..lets suppose
User A wants 5 columns
User B wants 8 columns to enter data
he will wirte count in textbox and then we have to create columns in grid view [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWwwK.png)
Sample doc attached

guide how it is possible using jquery

Comment: The problem is not 4 or 9 columns. The issue is who going to not only say they want 8 columns, but THEN give each column a name. but FAR worse then, is how and where to you plan to save this data, since you really don't have much means to decide what kind of database, since end users can't be expected to have advanced database knowledge. So, asking user if they want 4 or 9 columns? Not really hard, but THE NEXT part, and who's going to give a name to those 9 columns? And worse yet, where and how do you plan to save this data. So, asking for number of columns = easy, but giving names etc = hard

Comment: So, to be clear, you want MUCH MORE then asking user how many columns, but THEN you need to ALSO ask the user for the names of the columns, and then ALSO need to ask the user for heading and layout you want at the top of the grid? Who's going to make up those names, and if everyone gives everything a different name, then you don't have a foundation to build a database on such a design.

Comment: you need to create an interface where the user can pick which columns they want then upon submittal you can query those specific columns

Comment: It is not clear here - perhaps you want the user to select existing columns? But, asking the user to create columns, give the column a name, give a heading name, and ALSO choose the data type, such a date, or number or currency etc.? That's a really tall order, since now the end user has to become a database developer, right? So, allowing the user to select some existing columns? Sure, no problem. So, this comes down to the scope of your problem. Select some columns = easy. Allowing the user to create database columns = hard, and not practical.